# Rearrangement based on matching text in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I will try and keep this as simple as possible. I have a list of names (first, last) in one column (A), then I get a second list which is usually about a quarter of the list in column A.

I want the cells in column B (the short list) to automatically rearrange so that the names are next to the name that matches in column A.

If there is anyone nice enough to tell me, if this match happens how I would go about getting the word present to be entered in the very next column corresponding to the name on another sheet in the same workbook.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: while the second part of my question would require some code i was hoping there would be some simple function for the first part which is the most important part, i have been unsuccessfully searching  for 2 weeks on how to make the cells in column b (the short list) to automatically rearrange so that the names are next to the name that matches in column A. Either way sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Please, read the links provided by RonRosenfeld, especially the last one. I edited your question in an attempt to make it better to read, but I still did not understand what you want. Edit the question to include a reproducible example, and show what the result should look like. Good luck.

Comment: As Andre has said, we need examples. I think I get you, but need something to go by, what have you tried, what are you trying to achieve perhaps a picture of what you want. Are they exact matches? if so look at `vlookup` or the combination of `if` and `countif`

Answer (score 0):

As Glitch_Doctor said, you could use vlookup, but put the vlookup in col B using column A as the reference value and the short list as the array. This would only populate when there is a match - excepting typo's ...